# filePath.getFileName() behaves differently

Tags: java, java-7

I tried the use of Path interface;

```
//get a path object with relative path
Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\Test\\filename.txt");
System.out.println("The file name is: " + filePath.getFileName());
Path filePath2 = Paths.get("/home/shibu/Desktop/filename.txt");
System.out.println("The file name is: " + filePath2.getFileName());
```

The out put is like;

```
The file name is: C:\Test\filename.txt
The file name is: filename.txt
```

For the windows file it printed full path and for linux file it printed only file name.

Why this difference?

Comment: Did you run all four lines on Windows or on Linux or did you run the first two on Win and the last two on Linux?

Comment: All lines are in Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: On Linux, the only illegal characters in a file name are `/` and the 0 byte. Everything else, including `\`, line feed and escape sequences, are valid.

That means `C:\Test\filename.txt` is a valid file name on Linux. The Java runtime doesn't attempt to be smart and guess that this might be a Windows path.

Note that this is different when you use `/`: This is a valid path delimiter on Windows when using Java. So the path `a/foo.txt` is a relative path both on Linux *and* Windows.

This means you can open files on Windows using `Paths.get("/C:/Test/filename.txt");`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Normal File operation will throw error if we used path like"/C:/Test/filename.txt" in windows.

Comment: I've been using the pattern for more than 10 years now. What do you mean by "normal file operation" and which error do you get?

Comment: File file = new File(/C:/Test/filename.txt); , FileNotFoundException,
As the file seperator is "\" in windows.

Comment: :-/ Try `C:/test/filename.txt`.